# MYOB api for custom data addition

Tags: myob

I want to know if there is an api for java to integrate the data from the site into the myob database like inventory of a customer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on which "MYOB database" you are referring to.

1. "v19" product range: use a [JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_1_Driver_-_JDBC-ODBC_bridge).
2. "EXO": you can use [JDBC SQL-Server driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378749(v=sql.110).aspx), or use the REST API documented [here](http://developer.myob.com/api/exo/exo-api-overview/getting-started/).
3. "AccountRight Live" (desktop or cloud): use the REST API documented [here](http://developer.myob.com/api/accountright/api-overview/getting-started/).
4. "Essentials": use the REST API documented [here](http://developer.myob.com/api/essentials-accounting/endpoints/).
5. "Advanced": use the REST API documented [here](http://developer.myob.com/api/advanced/).

Note that solutions involving JDBC drivers typically require that your site be deployed on the same network as the target company file. If not, you will need an intermediate stage to synchronise or post data.